# Allow any company to send emails through Amazon SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is it possible to allow companies to send Email through their own domain using our SES account? The reason for this is, basically we have email templates people can send from our app, they're processed on our server, and sent through our SES account, but I'd like it to show the email coming from our customer's domain. Is this possible in SES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to have them add specific DNS records to verify that they control the domain.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

Comment: Any way to make the verification process simpler? Our customer's aren't tech savvy and therefore asking them to add records to their DNS isn't a solution.

Comment: If not, would it be possible to just boot up a cluster of EC2 based SMTP servers and replace SES with that?

Comment: You can do it for *individual* email addresses on the domain with an easier process. The DNS records are still important for spam filtering, though - SPF and DKIM are quite necessary. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

Comment: @DavidXu EC2's IP range is generally considered scorched-earth when it comes to email deliverability.

Comment: That sucks. Are there any other solutions to this? It seems SES won't be an option at this point, nor will EC2.

Comment: @DavidXu If they can't add DNS records, most of the email's not going to go through. SPF at least is pretty much a requirement for good deliverability these days.

Comment: How do other systems like HubSpot manage to do it without forcing people to modify their DNS records?

Comment: @DavidXu http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/How-do-I-setup-my-Email-Sending-Domains

Comment: @DavidXu without DNS records, you'll have mail ending up in spam folders anyhow. There's a reason SES and [Mailchimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/delivery/deliverability-research/about-dmarc) and [Emma](http://support.e2ma.net/Resource_Center/Account_how-to/Instructions_for_setting_up_Emma_as_an_authorized_sender)